# Toad ER Diagram is not showing relationships and pk,fk between tables

Tags: oracle, diagram, toad, erd, entity-relationship

I'm using Toad for Oracle v12.0.0.61 with admin module.
the database i'm interested in has 61 "views"
I selected all views, right clicked and chosen ER Diagram
Toad created small UML diagram for each table listing the table name and all their columns, but there are no indication of their primary keys or foreign keys and the relationships between them.
Even if I choose one specific table (main one), and right click on it and choose ER diagram, choosing say 5 level of details, it creates one diagram only for one table without all the other information.
Am I missing any step here or is this related to the level of access I have been given?

Thank you

Comment: "@Bob Jarvis" has the correct answer to your specific question. I've always been disappointed by Toad's ER diagram feature. It seems nigh on impossible to get a nicely laid out diagram out of it!

Comment: @PaulWalker - I've never found an automated diagrammer that produced usable diagrams. Automated diagramming seems to be sales-person-ware. "Yes, our product does that!" is what you're told. What is not mentioned is that the word "badly" should be inserted right before the exclamation point... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views don't have keys. Views are just canned SQL queries.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! Now I if i can find the actual tables from which the views were created, what should I do more to build the ER?

Comment: When I'm building an ERD I generally don't try to document/diagram where the data in the view comes from, as it could (theoretically, at least :-) be changed. I just treat views as a black box when diagramming. If you need to see where the data comes from you can see the view query in pretty much any GUI (e.g. Oracle's SQL Developer product, Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer, and others), or in SQL*Plus you can query the data dictionary, as in: `SELECT * FROM USER_VIEWS WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'YOUR_VIEW'`. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope the Developers who created the DB would have documented it. thanks again :)